# Where is the `--` (double dash) argument documented?

Tags: shell, options, documentation

There are some utilities that accept a `--` (double dash) as the signal for "end of options", required when a file name starts with a dash:

```bsh
$ echo "Hello World!" >-file

$ cat -- -file
Hello World!

$ cat -file                      # cat - -file fails in the same way.
cat: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

But some of those utilities don't show such an option in the manual page.

The [`man` page for `cat`](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/man1/cat.1.html) doesn't document the use (or validity) of a `--` argument in any of the OS'es. **This is not meant to be a Unix - Linux flame war**, it is a valid, and, I believe, useful concern.

Neither `cat`, `mv`, `ed` (and I am sure many others) document such an option in their manual page that I can find.

Note that `./-file` is a more portable workaround to the use of `--`.
For example, the `source` (dot) command (and written as `.`) doesn't (generally) work well with an `--` argument:

```
$ echo 'echo "Hello World!"' >-file

$ . ./-file
Hello World!

$ . -file
ksh: .: -f: unknown option
ksh: .: -i: unknown option
ksh: .: -l: unknown option
ksh: .: -e: unknown option
Usage: . [ options ] name [arg ...]

$ . -- -file         # works in bash. Not in dash, ksh, zsh.
ksh: .: -file: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Comment: New GNU/Linux users would really benefit from this question. The canon is "read the manpage", but here is some valuable info that one just won't find there.

Answer (score 86):

This is a POSIX requirement for all utilities, see [POSIX chapter 12.02](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02),
Guideline 10 for more information:

> The first **--** argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `'-'` character.

POSIX recommends all utilities to follow these guidelines.

There are a few exceptions [like `echo` (read at OPTIONS)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). And [special builtins that do not follow the guidelines (like `break`, `dot`, `exec`, etc.)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14) :

> Some of the special built-ins are described as conforming to XBD Utility Syntax Guidelines. For those that are not, the requirement in Utility Description Defaults that "--" be recognized as a first argument to be discarded does not apply and a conforming application shall not use that argument.

The intent is to document all commands that do not follow the guidelines in their POSIX man page, from [POSIX chapter 12.02](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) third paragraph:

> Some of the standard utilities do not conform to all of these guidelines; in those cases, the OPTIONS sections describe the deviations.

As [the `cat` POSIX man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) documents no deviations in the OPTIONS section, it is expected that it accept `--` as a valid argument.

There still may be (faulty) implementations that fail to follow the guideline.

In particular, most [GNU core utilities follow this guideline](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Common-options)

Comment: what is exactly POSIX's stance on programs which do not take any _arguments_, but only _operands_, like `dd`. Should they recognize the `--` or not? FWIW, FreeBSD's `dd` does not accept it.

Comment: Good question. Solaris `dd` calls `getopt()` with an empty `optstring` and this could be seen as a hint that Sun believes `dd` should support it as they added this call in order to get XPG4 compliance.

Comment: Debian `dd -- if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1` works as expected, by simply ignoring `--`, it seems

Comment: Rest in peace, schily

Answer (score 10):

For Linux OS that have a GNU userland: Debian, RedHat, Ubuntu, Mint, etc. (not some BSD's) the GNU common practices are important:

The list of utilities in your question have in common that they are GNU, in fact they all are GNU coreutils. The [full GNU coreutils list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GNU_Core_Utilities_commands) is longer.

Most of the utilities from GNU share a common user interface and a common set of basic command line options like `--help`, `--version` and the use of `--` as the signal for *end of options*.

The entry at `info common` and [the GNU web page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Common-options) contain:

> Certain options are available in all of these programs. Rather than writing identical descriptions for each of the programs, they are described here. (In fact, every GNU program accepts (or should accept) these options.)
>
> ‘--’
> Delimit the option list. Later arguments, if any, are treated as operands even if they begin with ‘-’. For example, ‘sort -- -r’ reads from the file named -r.

A more precise (but not that easy to explain and remember) command to get to the `--` entry is (please copy exactly) `info -- cat --`.

Answer (score 2):

It is also documented in [`getopt(1)`](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/man1/getopt.1.html) and [`getopt(3)`](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/Linux/man3/getopt.3.html).

For example,

> Each parameter after a `--' parameter is always interpreted as a non-option parameter.

Comment: Which is useful to a developer, but a user of utility will not know if it uses getopt. It's also unlikely such a technical decision would be documented in a user manual for utility.

Answer (score -4):

`--` signals the end of options and disables further option processing, it is the part of a shell you use.

The same like `man cat` does not describe that space is delimiter between command options, because it is described in manual to your shell.

What shell do you use, **/bin/bash** ? So the answer to you question is `man bash`, because it is explained there as part of shell functionality, it is not a part of a command functionality.

---

**Updated: This is Incorrect**

Thank you for correcting me.
The things I mentioned are correct for most of built-in shell commands (except if it is mentioned otherwise in manual). But in case of external commands, it is about POSIX conventions.

Comment: No, this is not part of the shell.

Comment: @Quasímodo `man bash` only documents the options valid when **calling bash**, like `bash -- -file`. the other utilities may (and do) process arguments in their own particular way.

Comment: @Isaac Yes, the header in the corresponding `man bash` section lets no doubt: "bash interprets the following options when it is invoked".