# What happens to arguments passed to bash/ash functions?

Tags: bash, openwrt, ash

[This answer about --](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570733/88800) gives a lot of good information about using `--` in POSIX shells and [this answer about passing all arguments to a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824637/1666926) led to the following function:

```
my_echo()
{
    set -x
    echo $@ " " \"$@\"
    echo `ps | grep -- "$@" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'` 2>/dev/null
    set +x
}

my_echo logread -f
```

I'm writing this script for OpenWRT. The output from ash shows

```
+ echo logread -f   "logread -f"
logread -f   "logread -f"
+ ps
+ grep -v grep
+ awk { print $1 }
+ grep -- logread -f
grep: -f: No such file or directory
+ echo

+ set +x
```

Huh...the quotes I added to the grep command are gone (logread -f is left unquoted).

I tried this function in bash

```
+ echo logread -f ' ' '"logread' '-f"'
logread -f   "logread -f"
++ ps
++ grep --color=auto -- logread -f
++ grep --color=auto -v grep
++ awk '{ print $1 }'
grep: -f: No such file or directory
+ echo

+ set +x
```

Interesting...maybe my arguments are being parsed separately? To test this theory, I tried:

```
my_echo "logread -f"
```

Bash Output:

```
+ echo logread -f ' ' '"logread' '-f"'
logread -f   "logread -f"
++ ps
++ grep --color=auto -- 'logread -f'
++ grep --color=auto -v grep
++ awk '{ print $1 }'
+ echo

+ set +x
```

The output of the echo command didn't change (the `set` version or the actual output but `logread -f` now seems to be treated as if in double quotes. So...I got lucky because I misinterpreted `set`'s translation of my commands. BUT, my function works now.

Ash Output:

```
+ echo logread -f   "logread -f"
logread -f   "logread -f"
+ ps
+ grep -v grep
+ awk { print $1 }
+ grep -- logread -f
+ echo

+ set +x
```

And now I'm getting what I expected. It turns out, running `my_echo` with arguments passed in double quotes (single argument) is the same as

```
my_echo_new()
{
    echo `ps | grep -- "$1" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'` 2>/dev/null
}

my_echo_new "logread -f"
```

So...it sure seems like the issue is with working with multiple arguments. What is going on here? Is this a result of the ` or the result of the function call or something else? Why do I need double quotes in both places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"$@"` expands to a *list* of quoted strings.  If you pass the two arguments `logread` and `-f` to your function, then `"$@"` would expand to *two* strings.

Running `grep -- "$@"` would therefore expand to `grep -- logread -f`, which means "grep for `logread` in the file called `-f`".

Would you want to pass separate arguments rather than a single string, then use `"$*"` to expand the arguments to a single quoted string.

```
grep -e "$*"
```

would expand to `grep -e "logread -f"`.  The positional parameters would be delimited by the first character in `$IFS` when using `"$*"` (by default, this is a space).  Also note that using either `$*` or `$@` *unquoted* does not make sense.

As an aside, I would probably opt for using `pgrep`/`pkill` here:

```
if ! pgrep -xf "$*" >/dev/null; then
    printf 'No process matches "%s" exactly\n' "$*"
fi
```